# SVG DOM Objects spacing/Overlapping

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I am creating a sort of a time line chart where I am creating rectangles using SVG DOM and then dynamically displaying them in  of a table in html. The problem is that each time a table cell contains two SVG objects, it automatically shifts the second one  to the next line . I want them to display on the same line without any space and possibly overlap where I require them to.
I have tried all things like line-spacing, height, float, padding, margins but nothing seems to work here. I am writing a part of my code below. This part of the code is inside a loop and repeats a number of time creating multiple SVG Dom objects at multiple instances:

```
var rect=function(h,w,fill){


var NS="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
SVGObj.width.baseVal.value=w;
SVGObj.height.baseVal.value=h;
SVGObj.setAttribute("height",h);
SVGObj.style.fill=fill;
return SVGObj;
}


var td1 = document.getElementById(date.toString()+start_hour.toString());
var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
var NS="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
var svg=document.createElementNS(NS,"svg");
svg.style.width=wid;
svg.style.paddingLeft = pad.toString()+"px";
newdiv.appendChild(svg);
td1.appendChild(newdiv);
var r= rect(100,wid,"green");
svg.appendChild(r)
```

Comment: It would be better, if you can provide us a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

The div your creating has default display property: `display:block`

This causes it to be displayed on a new line. 
You don't need to wrap your content into a div. The more semantic way would be to wrap it in a **<svg>** element instead.

Set the css `position:absolute;`, `top:0;` and `left:0` 
For a quick fix to displaying them ontop of eachother.

The easiest way would be make a css class.

```
.overlap {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

and then in your javascript:

```
element.classList.add('overlap');
```